# Awesome WM: Move window from one screen to another

Tags: lua, multiple-monitors, awesome-wm

How can I program the rc.lua file to enable a keyboard shortcut to move a window from one tag on one screen to a tag that is on a different screen? I know the **modkey + shift + [tag number]** shortcut, but that moves the window only to a different tag on the same screen.

For example: I want to move a window from the first tag on screen one to the third tag on screen 2 (or at least to the active tag on screen 2).

Comment: I came here expecting an answer for this question. I don't know why was closed, but in any case, in awesome 3.5 I found the answer inspecting the rc.lua file: modkey+O (`awful.key({modkey, }, "o", awful.client.movetoscreen)`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This should have been moved to superuser NOT closed.

Comment: Your answer saved me a lot of effort thanks!

Comment: This is also answered on superuser : https://superuser.com/questions/1037537/how-do-i-access-a-window-on-another-screen-using-awesome

Comment: This should not have been closed.

Comment: now it is `Alt+Shift+n` where n is the number of the tag/desktop. Ex `alt+shift+5` moves current focused window to desktop 5.

Comment: Comment of the year :D